# Open app through email without choosing from menu

Tags: ios, xcode, mime-types, uti

I have a custom file type that needs to be opened within our app, but when I tap the file, a menu is presented asking if I want to open the file in Messages, Mail, Slack, Notes, and *then* our application. How can I get it so that the app opens automatically? Or at least get our app to the front of the list of possible applications.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can't remove other apps from being able to open the UTI.

you can't influence the order of apps in the dialog

===

IF that is our own filetype, change the file's UTI ;)